# Passing slug field into template form action and views

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I have two models first is **Service** that contains all of provided services and second is the **Order** for users if they want to order any kind of Service.

service model

```
class Service(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, allow_unicode=True, default='-')
    current_queue = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    max_queue = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super(Service, self).save(args, kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.title} {self.current_queue}'
```

order model

```
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class OrderService(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user} {self.service}"
```

**Order** form

```
from django import forms

from .models import OrderService


class UserOrder(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderService
        fields = ['description']
```

what I want to do is : When a user choose any service, service name and the user gets by my views automatically (user by his request and service by its slug), but the problem is when I try to get the form, the slug field doesn't work, I think the problem is the template because when I send no action it doesn't do anything but when I send the slug into action it launch error and says no url match for this url

views.py in **Order**

```
@login_required(login_url='LOGIN')
def order_for_service(request, slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserOrder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = form.save(commit=False)
            object.user = request.user
            object.service = Service.objects.get(slug=slug)
            service = Service.objects.get(slug=slug)
            service.current_queue += 1
            object.save()
            service.save()
            return redirect("HOME")
    else:
        form = UserOrder()
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "order.html", context=context)
```

the **Order** template

```
{% extends 'root.html' %}

{% block documents %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form action="{% url 'ORDERING' slug %}" method="post">
                {{form.as_p}}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock documents %}
```

urls.py in **Order**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:slug>/', order_for_service, name='ORDERING'),
]
```

if you need forms or anything else tell me.

maybe it has a simple way to solve, but I can't figure it out. so if anyone can help me, please send me a tip or solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your UserOrder form too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in views.py in **Order** app and that is I saved the service not the object :)
and that was a silly problem ...
and by the way I correct my question and I have a new problem with this code and that is when the user submits the form the `service.current_queue += 1` did not triger and user should not redirect to the home page. can anyone solve this ? thanaks.

yeah, I never think that if I sleep for 2 hours, all of my problem get solved. I correct my question again and solved my prolems. the problem was I forget to save that specific service that's it!